# How to pass execution to form submit handler when there is an ajax callback in the form which calls drupal_session_regenerate?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

The form submit handler of my custom form is not being called due to session reset. What needs to be done to ensure that it is being called after session regenrating.

I converted a 2 step form that registers the user in the first step and allows them to make credit card payments in the next step into a 'single' step form. The user registration and auto login are handled by Ajax callback which creates the users and then calls drupal_sesssion_regenrate. This if of course resets the form token and the form submit handler is not called. I want to make sure that execution passes to the form submit handler. How can we do this?

Comment: could you possibly pass the form token or form_state to the ajax call and then return it after the session regenerate, which hopefully enable you to rebuild the form?